# Is $\forall X\subseteq Y$ an acceptable notation for "for all subsets of $Y$"?

Tags: logic, notation

I want to specify the domain of discourse for a well-formed-formula.

I know that in set theory
$$\forall x(P(x)\impliedby(x\in X))$$
is notated
$$\forall x\in X(P(x))$$
where $P$ is a predicate for a relation or property.

Using this intuition, can I thus notate
$$\forall X(P(X)\impliedby(X\subseteq Y))$$
as
$$\forall X\subseteq Y(P(X))$$
?

If this is not acceptable, would the notation
$$\forall X\in\mathcal{P}(Y)$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the functional predicate for the power set operation, be acceptable?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Why did you decide to change the meaning of Isaac's post? It's certainly a correction, but now it's not what Isaac was asking.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oops, sorry, I misread the edit history -- I thought you (not Isaac) changed the notation in the text of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there's a logical mistake in what you've written.

The meaning of $\forall x\in X, P(x)$ is conventionally $\forall x, (x\in X \to P(x))$ and not $\forall x, (x\in X \wedge P(x))$. (I'm using arrow for implication.) When you write it with a conjunction, you're saying everything is an element of $X$.

Similarly, the meaning of $\forall X\subseteq Y, P(X)$ is conventionally $\forall X, (X\subseteq Y\to P(x))$. It's also fine writing $\forall x\in \mathcal{P}(Y),P(X)$ if you want, but there are a number of notations for powersets so you might need to explain what you mean by $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ wherever you use it.

Just for completeness, $\exists x\in X, P(x)$ is conventionally $\exists x, (x\in X\wedge P(x))$ and similarly $\exists X\subseteq Y, P(X)$ is conventionally $\exists X, (X\subseteq Y \wedge P(X))$. One thing that works out fine is that $\neg \exists x\in X, P(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x\in X, \neg P(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! Big help.

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff I added one more thing, just to clarify how this works for existentials vs universal quantifiers.

Comment: Just saw it, thanks.)